# How to fix the center of an image in one place for an animation?

Tags: html, css, image, animation, position

```css
img {
  width: 20px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
    <figure>
      <img
        src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuQYf.png"
        alt="This is a picture"
      />
    </figure>
```

I want to fix the center of this image in one place so that when the image grows, the expansion doesn't only happen in right direction, but both in the left and right directions, same for the upward and downward direction. (Here, it happens only in the downward direction.)

How do I do it? I tried setting `margin`s to `auto`, but that centers the image the whole page, but I want it to be left aligned. Also, it doesn't seem to work for upward and downward direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an achieve this by centering the image like this

```
img {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 20px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 56px;
  margin-left: 52px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
    <figure>
      <img
        src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuQYf.png"
        alt="This is a picture"
      />
    </figure>
```

Comment: Just wondering: were the values of `margin-left` and `margin-top` a guess? If not, how did you calculate them?

Comment: The values should normally equate to 50% of the width for margin-left and 50% of the height for margin-top as this is how much the image is being translated by. So margin-top: 56px and margin-left: 100px; But because your figure element is adding margin and also the body tag has margin I subtracted this from the margin top and left values to make it site nicely in the corner when expanded